# How to create a node with value of count()?

Tags: neo4j

Let's say I have few nodes with specific field. I need to count it and create a new node with this value. I've tried following:

```
MATCH (n: node)
WHERE n.val="some string"
CREATE (: counter {cnt: count(n)})
```

but have a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `r` in `count(r)`?
You can probably do this:

```
MATCH (n: node)
WHERE n.val="some string"
with count(n) as num
CREATE (:Counter {cnt: num})
```